# Override auctex adding brace after accent macro

Tags: auctex

I have

```
'(TeX-insert-braces nil)
```

in my customizations, which according to the document should mean that braces `{}` are not automatically inserted after macros via `TeX-insert-macro`.  However, when 
I insert the accent macro `\tilde` the braces are added, contrary to my wish.

I can trace this down to `latex.el` containing

```
   (TeX-add-symbols
    ...
    '("tilde" t)
    ...
   )
```

in the function `LaTeX-common-initialisation`.  As a result I have tried to override the setting by adding

```
(TeX-add-symbols '("tilde" nil))
```

to my `'LaTeX-mode-hook`, but this doesn't work.

How do I do this and
is there a systematic way to implement this for all accent symbols?

Note the list of such symbols is available in the `Math > Accents` menu, when math mode is enable (which I do by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want braces at all use `0` as argument specification:

```lisp
(TeX-add-symbols '("tilde" 0))
```

See the [documentation of `TeX-add-symbols`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dadd_002dsymbols):

> ...
>
> `number`
>
> Insert that many braces, leave point inside the first. `0` and `-1` are special. `0` means that no braces are inserted. `-1` means that braces are inserted around the macro and an active region (e.g `{\tiny foo}`). If there is no active region, no braces are inserted.
>
> ...

Comment: +1 this works fine in the hook.  It is frustrating that `C-h f` TeX-add-symbols` does not provide this information.  Anyway, any ideas about doing this systematically for all (math) accents?

Comment: How about a `dolist` over all accent macros?  `TeX-add-symbols` description isn't really detailed because it's autogenerated by a macro.